# Entity framework - Updating list when updating object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Assume I have a class that is in a independent package and that could be used by Multiple object, for ex:

```
public class TimeSlot 
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Not this TimeSlot can be referenced from both the classes below:

```
public class Business
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TimeSlot> OpeningHours { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Delivery
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TimeSlot> DeliveryHours { get; set; }
}
```

Using Entity Framework code-first, this will result in a `TimeSlot` table containing both foreign keys to `Business` and `Delivery` objects.

Assume I modify a `Business` object (clear the list of the `OpeningHours` and add new ones in the code) and update it; once updated, the old `TimeSlot` records will have the `BusinessId` foreign key set to NULL instead of being deleted. 
What's the correct implementation in order to delete those records since they are no longer needed (and preferably without polluting the `TimeSlot` object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EF it's pretty elaborate to delete child collection elements. When you clear the collection or remove items from it, EF plays safe and does not assume you want to delete the objects, but only want to break the association.

So you have to remove the child items explicitly:

```
db.TimeSlots.RemoveRange(business.OpeningHours);
db.SaveChanges();
```

(`RemoveRange` is EF 6, with earlier versions you have to loop through `business.OpeningHours` and do `db.TimeSlots.Remove()`).

Answer (score 2):

Change in OnModelCreating in your DbContext class. Add willCascadeOnDelete to true.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

     modelBuilder.Entity<Business>()
      .HasOptional(a => a.OpeningHours)
      .WithOptionalDependent()
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. However, this does not work. I couldn't find WithMany; I found HasMany instead and tried to use it but then WillCascadeOnDelete cannot be called in the chained calls.

Comment: Please check now. I updated answer. Hope so this time it will work.

Comment: Now I get : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ZMvcHelpers.Models.Time.TimeSlot]' to type 'ZMvcHelpers.Models.Time.TimeSlot'.

Comment: I am sorry but it is still not working... I showed you the error message when doing update-database. Your solution does not solve the issue :(

Comment: 'modelBuilder.Entity<Business>().HasOptional(e => e.OpeningHours).WithOptionalPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);' @zahikaram